# creating a hard link between two files

Tags: linux

If I know that file1 and file2 are the same (they are duplicates), is there anyways that I can replace file2 with a hardlink to file1? I tried to use

```
ln file2 file1
```

Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ln -f file2 file1`

> ```
>    -f, --force
>           remove existing destination files
> ```